# How to save couple forms of same model class?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

How to save couple forms of same model?

Here is example, I have one model with a lot of fields, so I decided to create a couple forms with different model fields of that model instead of creating one big form because site requires custom styling for each part of data, so it easer to group input fields with same style to one form.

```
def add_pet(request):
        form1 = PetMainInfoForm()
        form2 = PetFoodForm()
        form3 = PetDescriptionForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form1 = PetMainInfoForm(request.POST)
            form2 = PetFoodForm(request.POST)
            form3 = PetDescriptionForm(request.POST)
            if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid() and form3.is_valid():
                form1.save()
                form2.save()
                form3.save()
                return HttpResponse('ok ok ok')
        return render(request, 'add_pet.html', {'form1': form1,
                                  'form2': form2,'form3': form3})
```

Comment: What's your question? Did you have any problem with your current approach? What error did you have?

Comment: Are you getting any error in this approach?

Comment: I made 3 forms for same model class. And now I don't know how to merge that 3 forms in one for saving. Maybe I need to use formsets or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using prefix for each form? Prefix should be unique for each form. This way, when you post back you know which form has posted. It helped me post multiple forms from same template. I hope it helps you too.

```
form1 = PetMainInfoForm(request.POST, prefix='PetMainInfoForm')
```